# Replace C statement with substitute in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I would like to use vim's substitute function (:%s) to search and replace a certain pattern of code. For example if I have code similar to the following:

```
if(!foo)
```

I would like to replace it with:

```
if(foo == NULL)
```

However, foo is just an example. The variable name can be anything.

This is what I came up with for my vim command:

```
:%s/if(!.*)/if(.* == NULL)/gc
```

It searches the statements correctly, but it tries to replace it with ".*" instead of the variable that's there (i.e "foo"). Is there a way to do what I am asking with vim?

If not, is there any other editor/tools I can use to help me with modifications like these?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use **capture grouping** and **backreferencing** in order to achieve that:

```
      Pattern     String sub. flags
    |---------| |------------| |-|
```

```c
:%s/if(!\(.*\))/if(\1 == NULL)/gc
```

```c
         |---|    |--|
           |        ^
           |________|
 The matched string in pattern will be exactly repeated in string substitution
```

---

[**`:help /\(`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C()

> ```
> \(\)    A pattern enclosed by escaped parentheses.                 /\(/\(\) /\)
>         E.g., "\(^a\)" matches 'a' at the start of a line.
>         E51 E54 E55 E872 E873 
>
> \1      Matches the same string that was matched by                     /\1 E65
>         the first sub-expression in \( and \). {not in Vi}
>         Example: "\([a-z]\).\1" matches "ata", "ehe", "tot", etc. 
> \2      Like "\1", but uses second sub-expression,                      /\2  
>    ...                                                                  /\3
> \9      Like "\1", but uses ninth sub-expression.                       /\9
>         Note: The numbering of groups is done based on which "\(" comes first
>         in the pattern (going left to right), NOT based on what is matched
>         first.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`:%s/if(!\(.*\))/if(\1 == NULL)/gc`

By putting .* in \( \) you make numbered captured group, which means that the regex will capture what is in .*
When the replace starts then by using \1 you will print the captured group.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
%s/if(!\(.\{-}\))/if(\1 == NULL)/gc
```

The quantifier `.\{-}` matches a non-empty word, as few as possible (more strict than `.*`).

The paranthesis `\(` and `\)` are used to divide the searched expression into subexpressions, so that you can use those subgroups in the substitute string.

Finally, `\1` allows the user to use the first matched subexpression, in our case it is whatever is caught inside the paranthesis.

I hope this is more clear, more information can be found [here](http://vimregex.com/). And thanks for the comment that suggests improving the answer.

Comment: Could you give us some explanations about what happens here? Otherwise we keep depending on you help in similar situations, isn't true? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

A macro is easy in this case, just do the following:

```
qa .............. starts macro 'a'
f! .............. jumps to next '!'
x ............... erase that
e ............... jump to the end of word
a ............... starts append mode (insert)
== NULL ........ literal == NULL
<ESC> ........... stop insert mode
q ............... stops macro 'a'

:%norm @a ........ apply marco 'a' in the whole file
:g/^if(!/ norm @a  apply macro 'a' in the lines starting with if...
```